# Android emulator stopping

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, android-emulator

So I keep having problems getting this to run. This is a tutorial pulled straight from the android basic training. I get the following error messages:

> 05-11 06:59:39.457: W/dalvikvm(623): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  ... 11 more
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.namespace/com.example.namespace.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.example.namespace.MyFirstAppActivity.sendMessage(MyFirstAppActivity.java:25)
>   05-11 06:59:39.617: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  ... 14 more
>   05-11 06:59:40.477: I/dalvikvm(623): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

Here are my two java files,

```
package com.example.namespace;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyFirstAppActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
}
}
```

and

```
package com.example.namespace;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;

 public class MyFirstAppActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myapp.MESSAGE";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Here's my androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.namespace"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.DisplayMessageActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MyFirstAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Everytime I run this, the minute "sendMessage" is called, I get "Unfortunately, myFirstApp has stopped." Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be

```
  android:name="com.example.myapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
```

changed to

```
  android:name="com.example.namespace.DisplayMessageActivity"
```

because there is no package **com.example.myapp**

Answer (score 1):

The answer in log.
" have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Add activity DisplayMessageActivity to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
```